# Question on adherent points

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I would like to ask why is $1$ an adherent point to the interval $(\,0, 1)\,?$ I understand that $0.5$ is an adherent point, but the interval does not really contain $1.$ Does this relate to concepts like supremum? Thank you very much!

Comment: each neighborhood around 1 meets the interval

Answer (score 0):

**Definition:** Let $x$ be a real number and $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a set. Then $x$ is said to be an adherent point of set $A$ if every open interval $(\, a, b)\,$ containing $x$, contains 'at least' one point of $A$.

Clearly, by the above definition, Any interval containing $1$ must contain 'atleast' points from $(\, 0, 1)\,$.